# LEFT JOIN on Max Value

Tags: mysql, left-join

Suppose I have the following two tables:

```
STUDENT
studentid   lastname   firstname
1           Smith      John
2           Drew       Nancy

STUDENT_STORY
studentid   dateline   storyid   status
1           1328313600 10        2
1           1328313601 9         1
2           1328313602 14        2
2           1328313603 12        1
```

Now, I need an SQL query that would select each student along with the latest story for that student in the student story table.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT s.*, ss.*
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM student_story
    WHERE student_story.studentid = s.studentid
    ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 1
) AS ss ON (ss.studentid = s.studentid)
```

However, this query does not work. It complains about s.studentid being an unknown field in the where clause of the sub query.

Please suggest how I can achieve what I'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  s.*,
  ss.*
FROM
  student AS s
LEFT JOIN
  student_story AS ss
ON (ss.studentid = s.studentid)
WHERE ss.dateline = (
  SELECT
    MAX(dateline)
  FROM
    student_story AS ss2
  WHERE
    ss2.studentid = s.studentid
)
```

Comment: Now when i think about it, this could return the same student twice if there were multiple entries with the same timestamp, so probably don't use this.

Comment: This should never be the case unless something is seriously wrong. How do I fix this query so it does not return the same student twice if there are multiple entries with the same timestamp?

Comment: If the ID's in the student_story table are also guaranteed to be increasing with time, you could instead select and compare maximum ID. This doesn't seem to be the case in your example though, so the problem is probably quite tricky. Didn't Vyktor's solution work? It seems quite reasonable.

Comment: @akanevsky That requires you to specify which one of the two stories with identical timestamp you'd like to receive.

Comment: Here LEFT JOIN will work as INNER JOIN because of WHERE condition and subquery. It should be like:
SELECT
  s.*,
  ss.*
FROM
  student AS s
LEFT JOIN
  student_story AS ss
ON (ss.studentid = s.studentid AND ss.dateline = (
  SELECT
    MAX(dateline)
  FROM
    student_story AS ss2
  WHERE
    ss2.studentid = s.studentid
))

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 
    s.sale_id,
    s.created_at,
    p.created_at,
    DATEDIFF(p.created_at, s.created_at) AS days
FROM
    pos_sales s
        LEFT JOIN
    pos_payments p ON p.sale_id = s.sale_id
        AND
    p.created_at = (SELECT 
            MAX(p2.created_at)
        FROM
            pos_payments p2
        WHERE
            p2.sale_id = p.sale_id)
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*, ss.*
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT * FROM student_story    
ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 1
) 
AS ss ON (ss.studentid = s.studentid)
```

Comment: I learned from all the provided answers but yours gave me a better job done.

Comment: This does not work because the sub select only returns one result for all students which can not be joined for all but the single most recent student_story.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an auto and unique id on each row on student_story table.

then you will distinguish between them. ( assume studentstory.new_id )

```
select s.*, ss.*
from student s
left join student_story ss on ss.studentid = s.userid
where ss.new_id = ( select ss.new_id from student s
    group by dateline
    order by dateline desc
    limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is making a `LEFT JOIN` with a `NOT EXISTS()` condition. Depending on the scenario, this can give a bit more flexibility; however, it will also show duplicate results if there are two entries with the same `dateline` per student:

```
SELECT s.*, ss.*
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN student_story AS ss ON ss.studentid = s.studentid AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM student_story AS ss2
     WHERE ss2.studentid = ss.studentid AND ss2.dateline > ss.dateline)
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN ON MAX VALUE(S)
This is a -quite verbose- query example of how to join the latest [max()] version of fields with the same ID, where latest version of these fields may vary separately in each table; e.g. the latest version of ID=1 from table1 to match the latest version of ID=1 from table2.

```
select td.task_id, td.duration, oda.task_id, oda.org_drtn_diff

from

(select * from task_dtl
where date_efctv = (select max(date_efctv) from task_dtl td where task_dtl.task_id=td.task_id)) td

left join
 
(select * from org_driven_actvty where date_efctv = (select max(date_efctv) from org_driven_actvty oda where org_driven_actvty.task_id=oda.task_id)) oda

on 

oda.task_id=td.task_id ;
```

Answer (score -1):

This join should do it:

```sql
SELECT s.*, ss.*
FROM student_story AS ss
LEFT JOIN student AS s
    ON student_story.studentid = s.userid
GROUP BY ss.studentid
```

`GROUP BY` should take last row, so last story = last row, if it won't work try to:

```sql
GROUP BY ss.studentid, ss.dateline DESC
```

*I'm not sure about it, please comment with result*

Comment: No. "the server is free to choose any value from this nonaggregated column " https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html